# Cannot install NUnit with Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget, nunit

I'm trying to install the NUnit package in my Xamarin Forms project and I'm getting this error:

```
   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
   Error Could not install package 'NUnit 3.9.0'. You are trying to install 
   this package into a project that targets 
   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not 
   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with 
   that framework. For more information, contact the package author. 0
```

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? It seems strange that there could be errors like this with such a common package...

Thanks so much!

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/installing-nunit-using-nuget/

Comment: `If you see NUnit 3.0 or higher, then you must downgrade to NUnit 2.6.4.`

Comment: Spend time learning the technology before using instinct like "such a common package". Different class libraries can be incompatible, and that's by design and with good reasons behind, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Comment: @Soluble Snake,  Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from below answers and Nkosi comments? If below answer resolved your question, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. If not, you can share the latest info about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

NUnit 3.9 does not contain any assemblies that are compatible with Portable Class Library (PCL) projects. It has a .NET Standard 1.3 assembly but [.NETStandard version 1.3 is not compatible with any PCL profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

So your options are:

1. Use an older NUnit NuGet version, such as 2.6.4, as suggested by Nkosi.
2. Convert your PCL project to a .NET Standard project.
3. Create your NUnit tests in a project that targets the full .NET Framework and have the test project reference the PCL project.

Comment: My solution for this on a project was to use .NET Core 2.0 target for the unit test project. That made sure I could run them in cloud CI providers that didn't have Windows environments, and they run just fine in latest Visual Studio 2017 Mac betas.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio adapter and the NUnit Console cannot run Xamarin based tests because they are both based on the full framework. You can however use the NUnit Xamarin runner to run on devices. See https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin.

Personally, I find it much easier to just target .NET 4.5.x in your test project and reference the Xamarin PCL project that you are testing. That allows you to use the latest version of NUnit and run your tests in Visual Studio or on the command line. See [Testing Xamarin Projects using NUnit](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/12/21/testing-xamarin-projects-using-nunit-3/) for more information.